# Dox (haxe documentation tool) package overview

Tags: haxe, documentation-generation, dox

Is there a way to generate what Java calls [package comments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment) with [Dox](https://github.com/dpeek/dox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this is not currently available.

You could request this feature at: https://github.com/dpeek/dox/issues

Comment: I created https://github.com/dpeek/dox/issues/104 . Let's hope they find it important too.